# How to make a js function that will source the virtual environment in the currents to other folder?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

I am using DRF Social OAuth2 for social authentication, it's giving me the token when I log in, but I want to return the token in response when I register a user with an email and password. How can I do that